# Initializing Firestore-Admin in Flask app

Tags: python, firebase, flask, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have a Flask app that uses Cloud Firestore for some functions. I am using the `Firestore-Admin` library which works fine, but I assume I placed its initializing code wrongly. My knowledge about how Flask apps work is limited so I just simply added the following code to my app.py:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('key.json')
fault_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
```

While the code works, my question is that is it a proper solution to initialize the Firestore? Does this solution fits into the lifecycle of a Flask app? I already tried to init the Firestore directly from the methods that use it, but that made server errors because the amount of initializations.

Answer (score 1):

Below Example Might Help you :

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

cred = credentials.Certificate("key.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

@app.route('/getdata')
def user_data():

#getting the docs

  users_ref = db.collection('Demo')
  docs = users_ref.get()
  for doc in docs:
      print('{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
  return "Recorded Printed"

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

Comment: This works but I had to add an '@' before 'app.route' to get it to run.

Comment: Thanks, @RiversCuomo Updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks reasonable to me. It's the same approach taken in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-developing-a-web-service-with-admin-sdk-flask-and-google-cloud-6fb97eb38b80).