# How to get Firestore collections and documents in Flask

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access my Firestore documents and collections from my Flask server. But any get() or stream() call hangs, such as:

`firestore_db.collection('users').get()`

I know my service credential is valid. My Firestore calls execute fine outside of the flask app. Moreover, when I create a new, very simple, Flask app (like this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52680204/6424258 ), the Firestore calls work.

Something about my full Flask app (which also uses sqlAlchemy and PostGres) seems to be messing up my connection to Firebase.

I see this in my log file after a call to Firestore:

```
Checking ***credfile***.json for explicit credentials as part of auth process...
Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443
```

I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're not _the_ Rivers, are you?

Comment: @duhaime 'fraid I am.

Comment: If you are and you find yourself back home in Connecticut in search of a home-cooked meal and some conversation about songwriting, it'd be an honor: 614-254-6978. My name is Jonas.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after much debugging I think I've got something here. When I comment out these two lines in the **init**.py file of my flask app, the calls to Firestore start working:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

I believe I was using those lines for a websocket chat app.